# How to check how many specific digits appear in an array of numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to check how many specific digits appear in an array of numbers. For example, digit 2 appears:

```
input from 1 to 20 
output
3 times
```

another example:

```
input from 1 to 100
output 
19 times
```

this is my code

```
int count = 0;
string x = "";
string y = "";
string[] arr2 = new string[100000000];
for (int i = 1; i < arr2.Length; i++)
{
    arr2[i - 1] = i.ToString();
}

foreach (var item in arr2)
{  
    for (int digit = 0;digit<item.Length;digit++)
    {
        if (digit == 2)
            count++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

My code doesn't work but i don't know where the problem is.

Note : This must be done with `for` / `foreach` loops only, not using `Dictionary` or LINQ or `DivRem`.

Comment: @mjwills i mean i don't want to use dictionary :D or ready functions

Comment: i mean can i do this with for loop ? @mjwills

Comment: @mjwills foreach ok but math.divrem not ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If you want to just use loops without the string array:

```
long count =0;
string x = "";
string y = "";

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 100000000))
{
    var s = i.ToString();

    foreach (char t in s)
    {
        if (t == '2')
            count++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

#### If you want to just use loops and the string array:

```
long count = 0;
string x = "";
string y = "";
string[] arr2 = new string[100000000];
for (var i = 1; i <= arr2.Length; i++)
{
    arr2[i - 1] = i.ToString();
}    

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
{
    var s = arr2[i];

    if (s == null)
        continue;

    for (var j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
    {
        if (s[j] == '2')
            count++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

#### If you are willing to use LINQ

Either of these solutions will work. The latter will likely be more efficient.

```
var count = string.Join("", arr2).LongCount(z => z == '2');

var count = arr2.Select(z => z.LongCount(y => y == '2')).Sum();
```

The former joins all the values into a huge string, and then counts all the `2`s in it.

The latter counts the number of `2`s in each individual string and then adds them up at the end.

Comment: Consider using [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, like `arr2.Aggregate((total, s) => total + s.Count(c => c == '2'))`

Comment: when i increase size to 10000000 it doesn't work for me

Comment: cmd display nothing

Comment: I have added a faster option for you at the start. _Note it does take a while to run @Yasmeen ._

Comment: ty @mjwills but how can i do this faster than your first way .. can i make this with digit comparing ? using if or while ?

Comment: There are many ways to improve the speed @Yasmeen . _I'd recommend creating a new question for that, since that is a slightly different issue._

Answer (score 5):

An efficient and concise method is to use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx) to sum the counts as you go, rather than counting then summing or similar (this approach only requires one pass through the array):

```
arr2.Aggregate(0, (total, s) => total + s.Count(c => c == '2'))
```

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
int total = 0;
foreach (string s in arr2)
    total += s.Count(c => c == '2');
```

---

If you don't want to use Linq or extension methods, then you can take the above code and just expand the remaining extension method:

```
int total = 0;
foreach (string s in arr2)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (c == '2')
            total++;
    }
}
```

Note that converting your numbers to `string`s before processing them is a bit wasteful - you can do this using the modulus and division operators `%` and `/` to inspect the digits directly (note that this code requires a minor tweak to work with negative numbers):

```
int total = 0;
foreach (int i in somearrayofnumbers)
{
    while (i != 0)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 2)
            total++;
        i /= 10;
    }
}
```

---

Alright, for the sake of completion - the nicest way I can think of to do this is a hybrid of the above:

```
int CountDigits(int in, int val)
{
    int total = 0;
    while (in != 0)
    {
        if (in % 10 == val)
            total++;
        in /= 10;
    }
    return total;
}

...

int digitCount = numbers.Aggregate((total, i) => total + CountDigits(i, 2));
```

Using [`Math.DivRem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yda5c8dx(v=vs.110).aspx) is pretty unreadable, hence sticking to `%` and `/` above.

Comment: where i should put this line because my pc going hang when i execute this

Comment: @Yasmeen You can replace your second loop with this (the `foreach` one). It may look like it "hangs", but if you're wanting to do computation on that many strings at once its going to take a while no matter your approach. Try lowering the size of the input and seeing if it gives you the right answer, then once you're confident, raising the size again.

Comment: error : object reference not set to an instance in this line 
foreach (char c in s)

Comment: how you assigned i into while where i into foreach ?

Comment: My mistake, long night.